# Having time-consuming object in memory

Tags: python

The code below is a part of my main function

```
def main():
    model = GoodPackage.load_file_format('hello.bin', binary=True)
    do_stuff_with_model(model)

def do_stuff_with_model(model):
    do something~
```

Assume that the size of hello.bin is a few gigabytes and it takes a while to load it. the method `do_stuff_with_model` is still unstable and I must do a lot of iterations until I have a stable version. In other words, I have to run the main function many times to finish debugging. However, since it takes a few minutes to load the model every time I run the code, it is time consuming. Is there a way for me to store the model object in some other place, so that every time I run the code by typing `python my_code.py` in the console I don't have to wait? I assume using `pickle` wouldn't help either because the file will still be big.

Comment: Could you **[split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)** the binary file into a smaller file for development parsing?

Comment: That's an option, but is there an alternative way? I feel like this problem occurs very frequently and would like to know if there's a good solution.

Comment: Perhaps (not a good idea by the way) you could set up python to automatically import it and add it to the builtins. Would still be time consuming, but only when you open up python. Or, if possible, try to reduce the model for testing purposes.

Comment: Pdb can  restart `do_stuff_with_model()` without exiting `main()` doesn't it?

Comment: @Basilevs How would you do it?

Comment: @MaximusS there are `jump` and `return` commands. You can `jump` within `do_stuff_with_model()` or `return` to `main()` then `jump`.

Comment: Ah yes, but if I want to run pdb after I have modified the troubling code I will have to restart from `main()`

Comment: Put the whole process in a ```while True:``` loop with a prompt at the bottom of the loop so the process never terminates.  - You would have to create the ```model``` object outside of the loop in the module scope and perhaps change the function argument to have a default value which is that object's name.

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a [ramdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)? If you have enough memory, you can store the entire file in RAM. This will drastically speed things up, though you'll likely have to do this every time you restart your computer.

Creating a ramdisk is quite simple on linux. Just create a directory:

```
mkdir ramdisk
```

and mount it as a `temps` or `ramfs` filesystem:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs ./ramdisk
```

From there you can simply copy your large file to the ramdisk. This has the benefit that your code stays exactly the same, apart from simply changing the path to your big file. File access occurs just as it normally would, but now it's much faster, since it's loading it from RAM.